# python - sorting nested dictionaries by total amount of items in nest?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that I would like to sort/reorder the parent dictionaries based on the total amount of sessions across all devices in child dictionary lists

**EDIT** im using python 3.6

With the below sample data, I would like the order

1. Manchester...
2. Edinburgh...
3. London...

How would I achieve this ordering, is it possible with this data structure?

```
{
    "London": {
        "EDGE-01": [
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "1",
                "bgp_session": "3:35",
                "bgp_routes": "0",
                "service_status": "Down",
                "circuit_name": "MPLS",
                "subnet_name": null,
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:45:43",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "MPLS"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Manchester": {
        "EDGE-01": [
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "1",
                "bgp_session": "1w1d",
                "bgp_routes": "2",
                "service_status": "Up",
                "circuit_name": null,
                "subnet_name": "Live ",
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:45:13",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "Live Primary"
            },
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "2",
                "bgp_session": "1w6d",
                "bgp_routes": "140",
                "service_status": "Up",
                "circuit_name": null,
                "subnet_name": "Dev Primary",
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:45:08",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "Dev Primary"
            }
        ],
        "INT-GW-01": [
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "10",
                "bgp_session": "1d2h",
                "bgp_routes": "10",
                "service_status": "Up",
                "circuit_name": null,
                "subnet_name": "PUBLIC",
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:41:58",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "PUBLIC"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Edinburgh": {
        "EDGE-01": [
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "1",
                "bgp_session": "3:35",
                "bgp_routes": "0",
                "service_status": "Down",
                "circuit_name": "MPLS",
                "subnet_name": null,
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:45:43",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "MPLS"
            },
            {
                "bgp_peer_as": "65001",
                "bgp_session": "1w6d",
                "bgp_routes": "140",
                "service_status": "Up",
                "circuit_name": null,
                "subnet_name": "SV Primary",
                "last_updated": "2019-05-08 17:45:08",
                "time_error": true,
                "service_name": "SV Primary"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't really ordered data structures.

Comment: you can use ordereddict from collections (stl), the order of that dictonary type is the order you create them, or bulit a class with mapping between 2 lists, or 1 lists of tuples, i can give an example if you would like

Comment: from python 3.7 dicts are ordered structures:
https://github.com/naftaliharris/tauthon/issues/86

Comment: im using python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @masasa suggested, you could use `OrderedDict` from the collections module:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

# You can use sorted to get the keys of the dict based on the len of all devices
# and reverse=True will order from longest to shortest
sorted_keys = sorted([(k, sum(len(dev) for name, dev in v.items())) for k,v in y.items()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# [('Manchester', 3), ('Edinburgh', 2), ('London', 1)]

# So to put this into OrderedDict
z = OrderedDict((k, y[k]) for k, _ in sorted_keys)

z.keys()
odict_keys(['Manchester', 'Edinburgh', 'London'])
```

For python3.7, you can just use a standard `dict` as @buran has answered and others have commented

Comment: I took `across all devices` to mean we should also consider the `"INT-GW-01"` key.

Comment: Ah, missed that key entirely, you're probably right. I'll make an edit

Comment: In python 3.7 you don't need to use an `OrderedDict`. That being said the OPs version is unknown so I would use an `OrderedDict` but you may want to add that disclaimer.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse True, I can add the disclaimer, but had OrderedDict at first since it's the most portable

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
spam = json.loads("""{
    ...
}""")

eggs = dict(sorted(spam.items(), key=lambda item: sum(len(value2) for value2 in item[1].values()), reverse=True))
print(eggs)
```

note that what you have is not valid dict (e.g. there are values like `null`, `true`), it is obviously json.

my solution assumes python3.7+ where dicts are ordered. if this is not the case eggs should be instance of collections.OrderedDict